# I am not seeing a desired result in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id=lol></div>

<script> 
$lol = $('#lol'); 
var st1 = "TEXT";

  $lol.text(st1).delay(1000).text(st1+"!").delay(1000)
  .text(st1+"!!").delay(1000).text(st1+"!!!");
</script>
```

What I want to see is

I want to see

```
TEXT for 1 second

TEXT ! for 1 second

TEXT !! for 1 second

TEXT !!! for 1 second
```

But it simply goes directly to TEXT !!! as soon as it runs

Thanks for your help Stack Overflow!

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/omuvzjkk/

Comment: delay is supposed to be used in conjunction with jQuery animation events (slideUp, fadeOut, etc). You'd be better off using a setTimeout to achieve what you want.

Comment: Just for fun, you can actually do this with `delay`, you just need a queue -> **http://jsfiddle.net/omuvzjkk/3/**

Comment: And for recursion you'd do -> **http://jsfiddle.net/omuvzjkk/4/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use delay for this purpose. You however use a simple setInterval for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/omuvzjkk/2/

```
var count = 1;
$('#lol').text("TEXT !");

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#lol').text($('#lol').text()+'!');
    if(++count >= 3) clearInterval(interval); // stop after 3 times
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed does what I want to do.

Comment: How about this one?  I want to see 

TEXT !
TEXT !!
TEXT !!! 
TEXT !
TEXT !!
TEXT !
TEXT !!
TEXT !!!

Comment: @HenderElstein - Thats easy, when count%3 is 0, reset text to "TEXT!" - as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omuvzjkk/5/